# What is the frequency of overs to introduce a "new" ball?

Tags: rules, cricket, equipment, officiating, icc

In ODI and Test they introduce a new ball in between the course of the match,which favours the seamers. What is frequency of overs in test matches for a new ball to be introduced,because it is a longer format game compared to ODI ?

Comment: Note that in ODIs, as of 2013 two balls are used for each innings, one for each end, making four balls used in total (ignoring occurrences such as losing the ball).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "2000 code" of the Laws of Cricket stated ([Law 5.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20170702052655/https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-5-the-ball)):

> In a match of more than one day’s duration, the captain of the fielding side may demand a new ball when the number of overs, excluding any part overs, bowled with the old one is equal to or greater than the prescribed number of overs. The Governing Body responsible for the match concerned shall decide the number of overs applicable in that match. This number shall not be less than 75 overs.

The Governing Body for Test matches, the ICC, have set this number at 80 overs. Therefore, in Tests, although there is no obligation to do so, the fielding captain may request a new ball after **80 overs**. The 2017 code updated the Laws slightly so that the number was fixed at 80 overs for all competitions ([Law 4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-ball)).

Furthermore, according to Law 5.3, either captain may request a new ball at the beginning of an innings; this is the normal course of events.